# How to assign different product positions in a category based on SKU?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I would like to assign different product positions for all the products in a specific category. For Example I got all the sku's and position numbers in a CSV file. Can anyone please let me know how do I do this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you want something like this: `INSERT INTO catalog_category_product(category_id, product_id, position) VALUES (282, 12750, -1);` and/or `UPDATE catalog_category_product SET position = 217040 WHERE (category_id = 282 AND product_id = 12750);`?

Comment: Firstly, Thanks for your post. I would like to update table from admin through csv file via php script. that's what I'm looking for........